# Flutter scroll has jittering on iOS 15.4 with promotion '120hz'

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, scroll

Flutter app scroll has jittering on iOS `15.4` at starts but after resume from the background will be smooth.

This issue is just on iPhone 13 pro and 13 pro max
I remove everything about heavy components and big images and create a new empty project just for testing and still have the same result.

And flutter version is Stable Chanel `2.10.3`

Tested on iPhone 13 pro max with promotion `120hz`

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(), //MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold( appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Scrollbar(
        child: ListView.builder(
          addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
          primary: false,
          shrinkWrap: false,
          physics:  const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: 300,
            itemBuilder: (contx, index){
              return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container( child: Image.asset('assets/ic_test_image.png', fit: BoxFit.cover),),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text('test scroll, dummy data',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange, fontSize: 30),),
                  ),
                  Container(height: 0.9, color: Colors.blue,)
                ],
              );
            }, ),
      ),);
  }

}
```

And in `info.plist` file, I added this to enable `120hz`

```
<key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: And in profile mode, it shows up '120 fps' in Android Studio

Comment: After building iphone 11 pro, xcode automatically generated for me the <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
<true/> . However after trying to rebuild it was not generated even after few attempts. I'm confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This has been fixed in Flutter 3.x](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/90675). From the [What's new in Flutter 3](https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-3-8c74a5bc32d0):

> **iOS variable refresh rate support**
>
> Flutter now supports variable refresh rate on iOS devices with ProMotion displays, including iPhone 13 Pro and iPad Pro. On these devices, Flutter apps can render at refresh rates reaching 120 hz, which were previously limited to 60 hz. This results in a smoother experience during fast animations such as scrolling. See flutter.dev/go/variable-refresh-rate for more details.